# How to change the BIOS splash screen on HP Pavilion G4 1303AU?

Tags: boot, bios

My cousin got a laptop model HP Pavilion G4 1303AU from the government of my state.
The laptop dual-boots Ubuntu and Windows 7.

Everything is great except the BIOS logo at boot which I would like to change but don't
know how to. I tried to flash a new BIOS firmware, but this didn't change the logo.

I found [this link](http://forums.mydigitallife.info/threads/47165-Please-help-me-out) for the same model and the same problem, but no success there either.
Also I saw this [blog post](http://donovan6000.blogspot.in/2013/06/insyde-bios-modding-advanced-and-power-tabs.html) which wasn't helpful, except for [this comment](http://donovan6000.blogspot.com/2013/06/insyde-bios-modding-advanced-and-power-tabs.html?showComment=1377971272094#c5245630656852511764) that mentioned an image in .ROM format.

Not wishing to decompile and recompile the BIOS, can someone help me out with a step by step guide ?

Comment: You can try the following guide http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?cc=us&lc=en&dlc=en&docname=c02693833 but if the computer was purchase by a state government its very likely they purchased it that way.

Comment: @Ramhound you mean to say they purchased it and then changed the splash screen of bios, but IMO its not the case. i tried to update the latest firmware and it flashed successfully but there was nothing changed even the bios firmware.

Comment: All I can say is that the tools HP provides an government agency are different then the tools they post for public use.  If you reset the bios using the hp's guide to do so, and the image does not change, then its very possible you are stuck with said image.

Comment: @Ramhound I found a tool named Flashi.exe from HP site but I can't get any download link for it, I just got a PDF link for those tools, and in that pdf they have mentioned that it can change the BIOS splash screen.

Answer (score 2):

The splash screen you are seeing probably comes from GRUB, the multi-boot manager,
which was installed by the Ubuntu installer when it was installed in dual-boot with Windows.

You should boot into Ubuntu, use `sudo` to edit the file `/etc/default/grub` and change the line that says `GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=<number>`, which specifies the number of seconds
that the  splash screen will be displayed.

Make that line read `GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0`, so the display will disappear after
zero seconds (no display) and save the file.

Then run `sudo update-grub` and reboot.

[EDIT]

As you say that you got got rid of GRUB, you are now left with the problem of changing the image that is burned into the BIOS itself.

The official HP BIOS for your computer can be found in this [download address](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/softwareDownloadIndex?softwareitem=ob-120487-1&cc=us&dlc=en&lc=en&os=4063&product=5280049&sw_lang=).
This will install the HP standard logo with the BIOS.

If you don't like this logo, then you need to modify the BIOS, which is always a risky
adventure. Ensure first that you have a boot CD or USB that can reinstall your current
BIOS, as the chance does exist that bad BIOS will brick your computer.

A tutorial that shows how to change the BIOS image can be found in Donovan's blog :
[Insyde BIOS Modding: Splash Screen Logo](http://donovan6000.blogspot.fr/2013/06/insyde-bios-modding-splash-screen-logo.html), which uses chiefly
Andy's Phoenix tool [Insyde BIOS](http://forums.mydigitallife.info/threads/13194-Tool-to-Insert-Replace-SLIC-in-Phoenix-Insyde-Dell-EFI-BIOSes) and other tools.
Read also the comments for the article which pertain to your computer model.

Comment: Sorry buddy, now I have deleted the dual boot and its only with factory reset to HP configuration. So is there any way to do this through windows or do I need to go back to Ubuntu?

Comment: You might try to (carefully) install [this HP BIOS](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/softwareDownloadIndex?softwareitem=ob-120487-1&cc=us&dlc=en&lc=en&os=4063&product=5280049&sw_lang=) then boot into it and search for splash-screen parameters, maybe under Advanced. If you find nothing, post a snapshot of the splash-screen so we can better understand the problem, and maybe also of the screen containing the parameters that might have something to do with it.

Comment: Harry I akready stated in my question I tried it but it does nothing.  But I'll give a shot may be that time due to grub it was not changed. And there is no splash screen parameters in bios at all. Splash screen has no parameters just to enter in the bios settings.

Comment: Haven't heard from you for some days, so how are things going ?

Comment: Buddy nothing is on the track yet. Situation is the same.  As I mention in comment I gotban pdf file from hp site via Google that Flashi.exe tool is able to do it but I didn't get the link for it.

Comment: I'm not sure that Flashi.exe is the correct tool. See my edit above.

Comment: I have already link the thread in my question where user have same problem with same model and he has tried the Donavan's method even Donavan is helping him to get rid off from it, but not succeeded yet. I ahve tried that firmware but it doesn't do anything, even it doesn't show up in the `msinfo` with its latest firmware.

Comment: I have unpacked sp62234.exe (latest HP BIOS) using 7Zip, and found the utility InsydeFlash.exe inside. Try to use Donovan's method with it. I don't have an HP and so cannot try it myself, but I'm trying to help.

Comment: You are welcome buddy. If it helps I'll gladly reward the bounty to you but if its not in that case too you will get the bounty. I'll not let it waste. Thanks for your help. By the way can you try to change the image using that method and upload the new bios image on devhost, dropbox for me?

Comment: And that pack will extract itself first and then from extracted files that is the kernel file which will flash on bios. See the comments link in OP.

Comment: InsydeFlash refuses to work on my computer - not an HP. But we can communicate via your post and screenshots. Try to follow Donovan's method while taking screenshots at every step until you get stuck, then add the screenshots with explaining text to your post.

Comment: Mate I tried that guide already, decompile the indsydeflash.exe and see if you get any .bmp or .png file there. I didn't get any. By the way bounty is yours for your efforts buddy, hope we will continue to sort it out buddy after this.

Comment: The splash screen is not inside indsydeflash.exe. It's probably inside one of the .bin files. Just follow the tutorial (it's our only guide) and post everything.

Comment: The user tried it already but didn't succeeded yet, I also link the MDL forum.

Comment: The file 0165EF6A.BIN seems to contain at least one bitmap. I can't help you if you don't give me information about what works or doesn't work for you with the latest bios.